# How to handle multiple rasters (precipitation data) in QGIS?

Tags: raster, grouping, precipitation

Currently I am working at a hydrological model for Rwanda which needs monthly precipitation data averaged over the area of subcatchments.

- The precipitation data are 144 TIF's from [CHIRPS](ftp://ftp.chg.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_monthly/tifs/) for timespan 2004-2015.
- The subcatchments are shapefiles

The output has to be a .txt file with the monthly precipitation data per subcatchment.

Is there a way in QGIS to group the 144 raster files and clip and calculate them together?

I use QGIS 2.12.1 with GRASS 6.4.3, Python 2.7 and PostGreSQL 9.6. Most of my experience is in QGIS and GRASS, and I am learning PostGIS since two weeks.